# how can I display specific user's post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display popular user's posts in wordpress and I can get the popular users ids with this code ;

```
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
            'meta_query' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'wp_popular_users',
                    'value' => $user_id,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                ) ) );
        if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
                echo  $user->ID. ', ';
            }
        }
```

and I can show the posts with this code ;

```
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                        "posts_per_page"=>8,
                        "post_type"=>"post",
                        'author__in'=> array(POPULAR USER IDS HERE!!!),
                        "paged"=>$paged
                        ) );

                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'profile-post' );
                    }
```

but I couldn't combine those two code, I need to insert user IDS in ***'author__in'=> array(POPULAR USER IDS HERE!!!),*** for example : 1,5,7

how can I make it ? thanks for answers

Comment: Make the top script wrapped in a function that you call into that array? Not 100% sure I get the full scenario here. The answer below should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to see if this works?

```
    $popularUsers = Array();
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
        'meta_query' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'wp_popular_users',
                'value' => $user_id,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ) ) );
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
            echo  $user->ID. ', ';
            $popularUsers[] = $user->ID;
        }
    }

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    "posts_per_page"=>8,
                    "post_type"=>"post",
                    'author__in'=> $popularUsers,
                    "paged"=>$paged
                    ) );

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'profile-post' );
                }
```